# MySQL query causing max connections

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I have the following query running against a MySQL db every 30 seconds:

```
SELECT message.id FROM message WHERE userto='13689' AND tstampviewed IS NULL AND message.status != 'VOID';
```

It shows up in my slow query log a lot, but it looks to me like it is optimized as best as can be.

The result of EXPLAIN:

SELECT_TYPE = Simple

TABLE = message

TYPE = ref

POSSIBLE_KEYS = userto,tst,stat

KEY = userto

KEY_LEN = 53

REF = const

ROWS = 1

EXTRA = "Using Where"

The keys userto, tst, and stat are all normal BTREE indexes, one for each of the varchar fields referenced in the whereclause of the query.  It is a MyISAM table with 300K rows.  Users do write to the table consistently, but reads are much more likely (10/1 ratio of reads to writes). The db server is Windows 2008 Enterprise with a lot of CPU and fast drives.

Over the past month, we keep getting max_connection errors, even though I increased the max_connections from 750 to 1500.  Several times a day, it seems like a query hangs (I can't verify this because I don't have access to the process list in real time), and 1500 queries pile up behind it and max out the connections.  This then obviously causes a lot of other problems.

The above query is the one that consistenly comes up in the slow query log, even though I thought it was optimized as best as possible.  Can anyone tell me otherwise or point me in the right direction to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you maybe run admin tasks such as `OPTIMIZE TABLE` or `ANALYZE TABLE`on a cron job? Those would stall other queries but would **not** show up in the slow query log themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not on the query - you are opening a connection to the database and not closing it, but opening a new one each time.

Comment: We make a connection to the db on each PHP page using mysql_connect.  PHP should close the connection at the end of the script automatically. We normally run with only about 20-30 active MySQL connections at any given moment.  Once the hung query finishes, the connections go back down to the average range.  It doesn't increment (ex. - it doesn't go from 20 to 30 to 40 to 50, etc.).  It almost immediately jumps from 20 connections to 1500 when the query hangs.

Comment: but the query doesn't create connections, it runs over the connection you open - what I am saying, unless there is a weird bug in MySQL you are looking in the wrong place. are you sure you don't have a redirect of a page to itself, a MySQLconnect inside a loop or something like that?

Comment: I might not have been clear.  The max_connection problem is because other queries get stacked behind the hung query, waiting on it to finish.  I just can't figure out why the given query may take 30 seconds or longer to run.

Comment: OK, I get it now! A possible problem is MyISAM uses table locking - is it possible you have a point where a write locks the table "message"? Another possibility is - does it happens with specific userto? Maybe a LARGE number of matches? Another weird thing a slow query should not prevent other queries from running - that's what multiple connections are for!

Comment: A write query would only lock the table it is writing to, correct? I have 150 databases, all with a "message" table.  It is weird, since a query on one db shouldn't lock the queries on the other db.  I don't have any one db that would collect 1500 connections within 120 seconds or so.  I can't figure out why the connections would max out randomly throughout the day. I guess the query isn't the problem, but some other hardware/software/unknown glitch!?  I don't really even know where to look now.

Comment: An INSERT or UPDATE would not cause a SELECT to appear in the slow log (unless the documentation is lying), as the time before having obtained the RW-lock is not counted. So, if the SELECT is spending several seconds acquiring the RW-lock, that has no bearing. On the other hand, if an INSERT is that complex, it should appear in the slow log itself.

Comment: I initially thought about transactions... but MyISAM does not support them... I wonder - can a query be considered "slow" because it produces a LARGE number of results?

Comment: I am marking this as the correct answer to close this question.  The problem was resolved when I converted from MyISAM to InnoDB, so I guess the issue was caused by one database table getting hung.